# How do I select single row in a group based upon date?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

We have an item price file that consists of Item number, Price Effective Date, and Price.
We are going to have a price increase at the first of the year.  What I want to do is add the price records now which would have a later effective date, and select the current price based upon the current date.  I.E. Current date is 08/03/11, I want to pull the ITEM1 01/01/09 record:

```
1. ITEM1    01/01/01    100.00
2. ITEM1    01/01/05    150.00
3. ITEM1    01/01/09    200.00
4. ITEM1    01/01/12    250.00
```

Once the first of the year hits - 01/01/12, I would select the 01/01/12 record.

You can't use MIN or MAX function as it would pull the first or last record, not the correct record.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry... I am using DB2 on AS400.

Comment: @Frederick: Updated my answer to reflect DB2 current_date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from tb 
join (
        select tb.item, 
        MAX(tb.effDate) effDate
        from tb
        where tb.effDate <= currentDate
        group by tb.item
    ) tmp 
    on tb.item = tmp.item
    and tb.effDate = tmp.effDate
```

Subquery will identify the correct row, and the main query will fetch the row again to get the price.

Answer (score 0):

You order by date, in descending order (so that the latest record is "on top") and use `WHERE` to filter out dates which are after the date youre instrested. The LIMIT clause (in case of mySQL) makes the resultset to have only one row. So query would be something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab
  WHERE(Number = ITEM1)AND(Date <= CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY Date DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: @kuru No, thats for what the `LIMIT` is there for - to return only one row.

Comment: I know...but I guess I mean, you don't know which one it's going to grab.

Comment: @kuru It would grab the latest date which is before the "current_date" because of `order by`

Comment: But LIMIT is not a valid function in DB2, received syntax error.

Comment: @Frederik I updated it to use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` instead - you didn't mention your DB engine in the question!

Comment: oops -- not paying attention -- you're right (with the order by).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date >= '01/01/09'

Comment: This selects all records greater than 01/01/09, I want the single row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT item_number, MAX(price_effective_date)
  FROM items_table
WHERE price_effective_date <  current_date 
    GROUP BY item_number
```

Comment: This is the one that worked!!! Thank you so much.   I knew I was missing something.  The code is a little more complicated as the dates are stored in CYYMMDD format and I had to put the conversion in the select statement as well, which was why I was having a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VB.NET, this can be very easy.  It looks like your fields are seperated by a single ' ' (space).  This will give you something like this:

```
Dim Record As String = "ITEM1 01/01/01 100.00 ITEM1 01/01/05 150.00 ITEM1 01/01/09 200.00 ITEM1 01/01/12 250.00"
Dim Fields() As String = Record.Split(" ")

Dim LastItemNo As String = Fields(Ubound(Fields) - 2)
Dim LastDate As Date = Date.Parse(Fields(Ubound(Fields) - ))
Dim LastPrice As Single = Val(Fields(Ubound(Fields)))

Debug.WriteLine("Item: " & LastItemNo & "; Date: " & Format(LastDate, "MM-dd-yyyy") & "; $" & Math.Round(LastPrice, 2))
```

In this case, it will output:
Item: Item1; Date: 01/01/2012; $250.00

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: nevermind, your questions changed substantially since I started writing my answer.  My answer now means nothing to you.  sorry

Answer (score 0):

If its just SQL you need try

```
SELECT [columname price] FROM [tablename] WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE()) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM [columname date] ) limit 1
```

replace `[columname]` with the name of the colum witch holds the data

replace `[tablename]`with the name of the table witch holds the data

I believe that should do the trick.